# How to Click a link In Selenium When Javascript, CSS and XPATHs aren't viable

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'd like to download a simple csv dataset by clicking the download button in Selenium. The button of interest is the "get the data" button below the big map. Here's my code so you can follow me.

EDIT: This code is written in Selenium for Python.

```
import time, os
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
preferences= {"download.default_directory": os.getcwd(), "directory_upgrade": True}
options.add_experimental_option("prefs", preferences)
#options.headless = True
options.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['enable-logging'])

url = "https://masks4all.co/what-countries-require-masks-in-public/"

# Path of my WebDriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install(), options=options)

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 15)


# to maximize the browser window
driver.maximize_window()

#get method to launch the URL
driver.get(url)


link = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#footer > div.footer-left > span.footer-block.get-the-data-block > span > a")

link.click
```

When you implement this code, Python complains of not being able to find the CSS selector, even though it's clearly there. I figured that the problem was maybe the webpage needed to wait a little and then be clicked via a Javascript query, so I also attempted

```
## The above, except

driver.get

time.sleep(3)
driver.execute_script('document.querySelector("#footer > div.footer-left > span.footer-block.get-the-data-block > span > a").click()')
```

I then tried simply using the XPATH

```
## the above, except

driver.get(url)
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "/html/body/div/div[3]/div[1]/span[5]/span/a"))).click()
```

If the button doesn't need for me to wait to click it, and no hidden roots/iframes are causing the issue... What is? Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 0):

Neither the CSS selector or the XPath are working for me either. You should test them in the browser using the Dev tools. Use `$$()` to find CSS selectors and `$x()` to find XPaths.

These work for me... CSS selector `"a.dw-data-link"` or XPath `"//a[text()='Get the data']]"`.

You can test them using `$$("a.dw-data-link")` and `$x("//a[text()='Get the data']]")` in the Dev tools.

See [Chrome DevTools help](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/) for more info.

NOTE: You'll notice how short my locators are. This is (generally) preferred so that minor changes to the page are less likely to break your locators. Also, XPaths starting at /html are always a bad practice for the same reason... they are very brittle.

Comment: when you say works for you, do you mean "The code runs and the file downloads appropriately?" If so, could you please post the code you used? I'll look at DevTools, in the meantime.